# facebook like button dynamic thumbnail with ajax gallery

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, facebook-like, thumbnails

i want to put a facebook like button to a website.
it is located on an image archive page.
the image archive is loaded dynamicly via jquery `$.post()` function.
the archive consists of a grid of images and a single image view.
when you click on an image in the grid a bigger version is loaded into the single image view. now i want to provide a facebook like button to share the website and as the thumbnail the selected image should appear.

the meta tag with the property og:image looks as follows

```
<meta id="active-image" property="og:image" content="http://mysite.com/default_image.jpg" />
```

when someone clicks on an image in the grid the content attribute of the meta tag is changed to the url of the current image in the single view.

```
$('#active-image').attr('content','http://mysite.com/detail_image.jpg');
```

as href of the like button i use

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://mysite.com">Facebook</a>
```

the problem is that the thumbnail which is provided by the popup facebook window is not the selected one.
is that because the page has to be "scraped" as stated here [faceboook: like plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)

does someone has experience in changing the og:image property dynamicly with jquery.
is it possible?

regards,
peter

Comment: i used this direct link as stated here http://www.schaefer-informatik.biz/blog/70/erweitertes-teilen-von-links-bei-facebook/

Answer (score 2):

> does someone has experience in changing the og:image property dynamicly with jquery. is it possible?

I have experience trying to change og meta tags using jQuery, however, it wont work.  The reason why is the Facebook linter only looks at the HTML in the response and does not run any scripts.  So your webserver code needs to be programmed in a way to be smart enough to serve Facebook the correct og meta tags.